# Bulk update data in iOS 7 CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, core-data-migration

Is there way to run updating of all objects for some entity by one SQL-query?
Not to fetch and run-looping.

For example like to run

```
UPDATE someEntity SET filed1 = value1 WHERE field2 = value2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercelo's answer will not work for iOS-7 for this you can

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchAllRSSItems = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[RSSItem entityName]];
NSError *fetchError;
NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchAllRSSItems error:&fetchError];

if (results == nil) {

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [fetchError localizedDescription]);
} else {

    for (RSSItem *rssItem in results) {
        rssItem.read = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    }

    [self saveManagedObjectContext];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but this will bring all objects to memory!

Comment: Yeah thats true , but if you are looking for backward compatible answer than you can use this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Core Data Batch Updates were introduced on iOS 8:

```
NSBatchUpdateRequest *batchRequest = [NSBatchUpdateRequest batchUpdateRequestWithEntityName:   [RSSItem entityName]];
batchRequest.propertiesToUpdate = @{NSStringFromSelector(@selector(read)): @YES};
batchRequest.resultType = NSStatusOnlyResultType; // NSStatusOnlyResultType is the default
batchRequest.affectedStores = @[...]; // Optional, stores this request should be sent to
batchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"..."]; // Optional, same type of predicate you use on NSFetchRequest

NSError *requestError;
NSBatchUpdateResult *result = (NSBatchUpdateResult *)[self.managedObjectContext executeRequest:batchRequest error:&requestError];

if (result) {
    // Batch update succeeded
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [requestError localizedDescription]);
}
```

However, it does not change the **context**: it changes the persistent store directly. This means that no validation is done and that you need to update your UI after.

This answer was based on [this post by Matthew Morey](http://matthewmorey.com/core-data-batch-updates/).

Comment: I ran into an issue where both result and requestError are nil....and executeRequest:error: is undocumented...wat do